# program converting infix to postfix notation

Tags: java, postfix-notation

I've been working on a school assignment that requires us to convert a string from infix notation to postfix notation. We have to do this by using a stack implementing an array.

Here is my code for the actual conversion class:
package practice;

public class Practice {

```
public static  String infixToPostfix(String infix)
{

    Practice2 operatorStack = new Practice2();
    String output = "";
    char curChar;
    String input = infix;
    boolean isOperator=false;
    boolean empty=true;
    int curCharPrecedence=0;
    int topOfStackPrecedence=0;

    for(int i =0; i<input.length();i++){

        curChar = input.charAt(i);

        switch(curChar){
        case '+': isOperator=true;
        case '-': isOperator=true;
        case '/': isOperator=true;
        case '*': isOperator=true;
        case '(': isOperator=true;
        case ')': isOperator=true;
                    break;
        default: isOperator=false;
        }

        if(!isOperator){
            output=output+curChar;
        }

        else if(isOperator){
        output+=" ";

            if(empty){
                empty=false;
                operatorStack.Push(curChar);
            }


            else if(!operatorStack.empty()){
                switch(curChar){
                case ')': topOfStackPrecedence=0;
                case '+': curCharPrecedence=1;
                case '-': curCharPrecedence=1;
                case '/': curCharPrecedence=2;
                case '*': curCharPrecedence=2;
                case '(': topOfStackPrecedence=3;
                }

                switch((Character) operatorStack.peek()){
                case ')': topOfStackPrecedence=0;
                case '+': topOfStackPrecedence=1;
                case '-': topOfStackPrecedence=1;
                case '/': topOfStackPrecedence=2;
                case '*': topOfStackPrecedence=2;
                case '(': topOfStackPrecedence=3; 
                }


                if(curCharPrecedence>topOfStackPrecedence){
                    operatorStack.Push(curChar);

                }
                else{

                    while(!operatorStack.empty()&&topOfStackPrecedence>curCharPrecedence){


                        output+= operatorStack.pop();
                        output+=" ";

                        if(!operatorStack.empty())
                        switch((Character) operatorStack.peek()){
                        case ')': topOfStackPrecedence=0;
                        case '+': topOfStackPrecedence=1;
                        case '-': topOfStackPrecedence=1;
                        case '/': topOfStackPrecedence=2;
                        case '*': topOfStackPrecedence=2;
                        case '(': topOfStackPrecedence=3; 
                        }

                    }
                        operatorStack.Push(curChar);
                }





                }
            }

        }
    while(!operatorStack.empty()){
            output+=" ";
            output+= operatorStack.pop();
        }

    return output;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   System.out.println(infixToPostfix("a+b*c"));
}
```

}

Then here is my code for the stack class:

```
package practice;

import java.util.EmptyStackException;



public class Practice2<T> extends Object{

public T[]  stack = (T[]) new Object[10];

    int topOfStack =-1;

    public Practice2()
    {
        stack = (T[]) new Object[10];
    }
    public Practice2(int capacity)
    {
        stack = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    public T Push(Object item)
    {
        if(topOfStack<=stack.length-1){
            T[] temporary = (T[]) new Object[stack.length];

            for(int i=0; i<stack.length-1;i++){
                temporary[i]=stack[i];

            }
            stack = (T[]) new Object[temporary.length+10];
            for(int i=0; i<temporary.length-1;i++){
                stack[i]=temporary[i];
            }

        }

        topOfStack++;
        stack[topOfStack]= (T) item;


        return (T) item;

    }

    public T peek()
    {

        return stack[topOfStack];


    }

    public T pop()
    {
        if(topOfStack==-1){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        else
            return stack[topOfStack--];

    }

    public boolean empty()
    {
        if(topOfStack==-1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int size(){
        return topOfStack+1;
    }



}
```

Whenever I try to run this I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at practice.Practice2.peek(Practice2.java:49)
    at practice.Practice.infixToPostfix(Practice.java:53)
    at practice.Practice.main(Practice.java:106
```

It appears that the problem is my peek method in the stack class, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've spent way to much time on this program and badly need someone else to take a look at it.

Comment: you dont need to do this... **class Practice2<T> extends Object** , every object extends the Object class by default...

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa hey thanks for the comment, just fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` ....

and the reason is here:

```
switch((Character) operatorStack.peek()){
```

you are doing a peek before a push... more specific: you are trying to get the element of the array located at the **topOfStack =-1** and that is the reason of the exception...

Comment: Yea I just figured that out, and changed around my else if statement before the switch statement to fix that. My program now compiles, but doesn't give the correct output. For the string "a+b*c" I get a b + c * as the solution when it should be a b c * +